# Mysql Is there a way to put all data under de same id in the same id in a single row?

Tags: mysql

I want to put al dates from de same user id in the same row next to each other

| user_id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 10006 | 18/05/2021 |
| 10006 | 28/05/2021 |
| 10006 | 16/06/2021 |
| 10007 | 18/05/2021 |
| 10007 | 28/05/2021 |
| 10007 | 16/06/2021 |

i have a table like this and i want to show it like this

| user_id | date1 | date2 | date3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10006 | 18/05/2021 | 28/05/2021 | 16/06/2021 |
| 10007 | 18/05/2021 | 28/05/2021 | 16/06/2021 |

i tried git GROUP_CONCAT() but that join them in the same cell, there is a way to show it this way?

Comment: how many dates are there for every user?

Comment: and which mysql Version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have mysql 8

But for the older Versions you can build a row_number

Edit: i added a dynamic Version of the query

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1
>     (`user_id` int, `date` varchar(10))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO table1
>     (`user_id`, `date`)
> VALUES
>     (10006, '18/05/2021'),
>     (10006, '28/05/2021'),
>     (10006, '16/06/2021'),
>     (10007, '18/05/2021'),
>     (10007, '28/05/2021'),
>     (10007, '16/06/2021')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> WITH cte AS (SELECT `user_id`, `date`, Row_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `user_id` ORDER BY `date`) rn
> FROM table1)
> SELECT `user_id`,
> MAX(IF( rn = 1, `date`, NULL)) date1,
> MAX(IF( rn = 2, `date`, NULL)) date2,
> MAX(IF( rn = 3, `date`, NULL)) date3
> FROM cte
> GROUP BY `user_id`
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id | date1      | date2      | date3     
> ------: | :--------- | :--------- | :---------
>   10006 | 16/06/2021 | 18/05/2021 | 28/05/2021
>   10007 | 16/06/2021 | 18/05/2021 | 28/05/2021
> ```

> ```
> SET @sql = NULL;
> WITH cte AS (SELECT `user_id`, `date`, Row_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `user_id` ORDER BY `date`) rn
> FROM table1)
> SELECT
>   GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
>                CONCAT('MAX(IF(s.rn = ', `rn`,', "', `date`,'",NULL)) AS date',`rn`)
>               ) INTO @sql
> FROM cte
> ORDER BY rn;
>
> SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT s.user_id,  ', @sql, ' 
>                   FROM (SELECT `user_id`, `date`, Row_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY `user_id` ORDER BY `date`) rn
> FROM table1) s
>                  GROUP BY s.user_id
>                  ORDER BY s.user_id');
> #SELECT @sql;
> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
> EXECUTE stmt;
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id | date1      | date2      | date3     
> ------: | :--------- | :--------- | :---------
>   10006 | 16/06/2021 | 18/05/2021 | 28/05/2021
>   10007 | 16/06/2021 | 18/05/2021 | 28/05/2021
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dce9a573da3b435869a59e9d5cc65fc6)*

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what i was looking for.